# Create several subsets with a loop using a char variable as condition

Tags: r, variables, subset

With a for loop  I want to create several different subsets from a data frame, namely 24 subsets of data frame, which contains hourly data.

```
Hour <- "21:00:00.0000000"
st <- subset(df, Time == Hour) does not work.
```

`df$Time` is a factor, e.g. "21:00:00.0000000"

In the next step I would need to change the Hour variable with the index from the for loop.

Any solution for that?

Comment: Your life would be much easier if you convert your "time" to an actual time-based vector.

Comment: You might be interested in the `split` function. (Although, you should consider carefully, if you need to split your data at all. After all, there are "split-apply-combine" functions.)

Comment: You may need `split` with `list2env` if you want to create several dataframes.

Comment: @akrun They might want to, but they shouldn't. A list of data.frames is much better than cluttering the workspace like that.

Comment: so far the easiest thing has been to convert the Time factor into numeric vector and the create subsets...